Can't display values from ESP32 via Flutter reactive ble
I am able to scan and find my esp32. But i cant read the values that are send from the ESP32. I can see them in other apps like Bluetooth terminal. What am i doing wrong?
So i think my main file, scan file and connect file are all working well, but in the data file, which describes the UI that is shown after the connection to the ESP32 was succesfull, i am not able to display the received values from the esp32.
On the esp32 side i am using a Esp32 pico kit and the code on the ESP32 is from a example on the github of micropython https://github.com/micropython/micropython/blob/master/examples/bluetooth/ble_uart_peripheral.py
I looked at several Examples and could not find out my mistake.
//my main file:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_reactive_ble/flutter_reactive_ble.dart';
import 'package:sk_app_4/ble/connect.dart';
import 'package:sk_app_4/ble/scan.dart'; // Importiere die Scandevice-Klasse
import 'package:sk_app_4/UI/data.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final Connect connector = Connect();
  final Scandevice scanner = Scandevice(); // Instanziere die Scandevice-Klasse
  DeviceConnectionState _connectionState = DeviceConnectionState.disconnected;
  late final DiscoveredDevice device;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _startScan();
  }

  void _startScan() {
    scanner.scannedDevices.listen((List<DiscoveredDevice> devices) {
      setState(() {
        // Aktualisiere den Zustand mit den gescannten Geräten
      });
    });
  }

  void _connectToDevice(device) async {
    await connector.connectToDevice(device, (DeviceConnectionState connectionState) {
      setState(() {
        _connectionState = connectionState;
      });
      if (_connectionState == DeviceConnectionState.connected) {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Data(device: device,)),
        );
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('T6S')),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 1, // Verwende die gescannten Geräte aus der Scandevice-Klasse
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int Index) {
                final DiscoveredDevice device = scanner.devices[Index];

                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    _connectToDevice(device);
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    height: 80,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text(device.name ?? '', textAlign: TextAlign.left),
                        Text(device.id, textAlign: TextAlign.left),
                        Text(device.rssi.toString(), textAlign: TextAlign.left),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );}
              ,
            ),
          ),
          Text('Connection State: $_connectionState'),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _startScan();
        },
        child: const Text('Scan'),
      ),
    );
  }
}


//The scan file:
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_reactive_ble/flutter_reactive_ble.dart';

class Scandevice {
  final List<DiscoveredDevice> _devices = [];
  final FlutterReactiveBle _ble = FlutterReactiveBle();
  final List<DiscoveredService> _services = [];
  Stream<List<DiscoveredDevice>> get scannedDevices async* {
    await for (final event in _ble.scanForDevices(withServices: [Uuid.parse('6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E')])) {
      if (event.name == 'mpy') {
        _devices.add(event);
        yield _devices.toList();
      }
    }
  }


  List<DiscoveredDevice> get devices => _devices;



//The file where the received data should be displayed:
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_reactive_ble/flutter_reactive_ble.dart';

class Data extends StatefulWidget {
  final DiscoveredDevice device;

  const Data({Key? key, required this.device}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DataState createState() => _DataState();
}

class _DataState extends State<Data> {
  final List<String> _receivedData = [];
  late QualifiedCharacteristic _characteristic;
  late StreamSubscription<List<int>> _dataStreamSubscription;

  // Update the following UUIDs with the ones from your ESP32 code
  static const String _UART_UUID = "6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E";
  static const String _UART_TX = "6E400003-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E";
  static const String _UART_RX = "6E400002-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _discoverServicesAndCharacteristics();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _dataStreamSubscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _discoverServicesAndCharacteristics() async {
    await FlutterReactiveBle().discoverAllServices(widget.device.id);
    final services = await FlutterReactiveBle().getDiscoveredServices(widget.device.id);
    for (var service in services) {
      for (var characteristic in service.characteristics) {
        if (characteristic.isReadable) {
          _characteristic = QualifiedCharacteristic(
            serviceId: service.id,
            characteristicId: characteristic.id,
            deviceId: widget.device.id,
          );
          _startReading();
          return;
        }
      }
    }
    print('No readable characteristic found.');
  }

  void _startReading() {
    _dataStreamSubscription = FlutterReactiveBle()
        .subscribeToCharacteristic(_characteristic)
        .listen((data) {
      setState(() {
        _receivedData.add(String.fromCharCodes(data));
      });
    }, onError: (dynamic error) {
      print('Error while reading data: $error');
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Data from ESP32'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _receivedData.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(_receivedData[index]),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

//my connect file:

import 'package:flutter_reactive_ble/flutter_reactive_ble.dart';
import  'dart:async';
class Connect {
  const Connect();

  Future<void> connectToDevice(DiscoveredDevice device,
      Function(DeviceConnectionState) onConnectionState) async {
    try {
      final connection = FlutterReactiveBle().connectToDevice(
        id: device.id,
        servicesWithCharacteristicsToDiscover: {},
      );

      connection.listen((connectionState) {
        onConnectionState(connectionState.connectionState);
      }, onError: (Object error) {
        // Fehlerbehandlung
        print('Error while connecting: $error');
      });
    } catch (error) {
      // Fehlerbehandlung
      print('Error while connecting: $error');
    }
  }

}

